# Cannot load MNIST data with the python-mnist package on Windows

Tags: python, package, mnist

I installed the python-mnist package via pip on my Windows device, just as described in the Github documentation, by entering the following command in my Anaconda terminal:

```
pip install python-mnist
```

This worked fine for me. However, when I am trying to load the data with this package like this :

```
import mnist
train_images = mnist.train_images()
```

I get the following error

```
AttributeError: module 'mnist' has no attribute 'train_images'
```

I am pretty new to installing packages in python and I am quite clueless as to why this is happening. I have been looking for other attributes that 'mnist' has and found that by going to mnist.MNIST I found a module that is called "train_images". However, changing the code to

```
import mnist
mnist.MNIST.train_images()
```

still gives the same error. I would appreciate any help on how to fix this error.

Comment: I would start with `pip show python-mnist` to check whether `mnist.py`  contains `train_images`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the documentation, you first need to download the data from the web (the 4 archives there: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) and then run:

```
from mnist import MNIST
mndata = MNIST('./dir_with_mnist_data_files')
images, labels = mndata.load_training()
```